# Javascript mailto string loses 'encodeURI' encoding

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

Trying to create a simple 'mailto' function using javascript. I just need to be able to send some links (like: See this article  bla bla).

Some of the links I need to send include spaces, danish chars. So I've been using the
encodeURI() function.

The problem arises when I try to mail the link (sample code below)

```
       var _encodedPath = encodeURI(path);
       var _tempString = "mailto:someemail@somewhere.dk?subject=Shared%20from%20some%20page&body=" + _encodedPath;
```

If I output the _tempString to the console I get the correct encoded string. However when using the same string in 'mailto' the string loses it's encoding and returns to the way it was before.

Any clue as to why this is?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean that it's showing a decoded link in the status bar of the browser when hovering? It could simply be that your browser decodes it to show a user-friendly mailto: link. Is your mailto: working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`.

More information [here](https://coderwall.com/p/y347ug/encodeuri-vs-encodeuricomponent).

Answer (score 0):

The link is decoded when you click it - that's normal.  Since you have an http link within a mailto link, it should be encoded twice.

Email clients do their best to make things that look like links clickable.  They typically decide where the link ends in a somewhat arbitrary and unpredictable manner.

In email, the best way to keep a link contiguous is to enclose it in angle-brackets like this:

<http://www.example.com/url with spaces>

But this isn't foolproof.  Email is fragile and you can't control the content well enough with a mailto link.  It might be better to try to reduce the complexity of the url - perhaps by providing or utilizing a url-shortener service.  Any url longer than 74 or so characters is likely to be mangled by some email clients.

Answer (score -1):

this site helped me solving any troubles with mailto links:

http://www.1ngo.de/web/formular.html

may be it's not the nicest way, but it always works with every browser i know. And it also has very cool algorithm implemented to format the content so that everything should be alright. Just try it and play around a little with code by quoting out parts of the code and you will understand very fast what exactly happens there and how to modify it for your wishes. Althoug it's a little late I hope this one helps anybody checking this question.

althoug it's in german, you just need to copy the code shown there and run it and experiment with it.

Comment: This is more or less a link-only question that doesn't specifically answer the question asked.